# Python: how to enclose strings in a list with < and >

Tags: python, string

i would like to enclose strings inside of list into <> (formatted like <%s>). The current code does the following:

```
def create_worker (general_logger, general_config):
    arguments = ["worker_name", "worker_module", "worker_class"]
    __check_arguments(arguments)

def __check_arguments(arguments):
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 + len(arguments):
        print "Usage: %s delete-project %s" % (__file__," ".join(arguments))
        sys.exit(10)
```

The current output looks like this:

```
Usage: ...\handler_scripts.py delete-project worker_name worker_module worker_class
```

and should look like this:

```
Usage: ...\handler_scripts.py delete-project <worker_name> <worker_module> <worker_class>
```

Is there any short way to do this ?

Greetings,
Michael

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
print "Usage: %s delete-project %s" % (__file__," ".join('<%s>'% arg for arg in arguments))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension: `['<%s>' % s for s in arguments]`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `join` bit with:

```
' '.join('<%s>' % s for s in arguments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
(__file__," ".join(arguments))
```

with

```
(__file__," ".join("<%s>" % a for a in arguments))
```